# Invalid use of incomplete type in Clang if I declare member function template with arg of containing class

Tags: c++11, clang

I'd like to implement a class like the one below with a member function template that takes a callable type F and applies it to the instance.

This compiles and runs in Visual Studio 15 but fails in clang with the error
[x86-64 clang 4.0.0] error: invalid use of incomplete type 'Foo'

```
struct Foo
{
   template<typename F>
   auto applyFunctionToMe(F&& func)->decltype( func( Foo() ) )
   {
      return func( *this);
   }

   int contents;
};

int main()
{
   Foo bar;
   auto result = bar.applyFunctionToMe([](const Foo& f){ return f.contents;});
   return result;
}
```

Is there a way to get this to work under Clang in C++11? 
Which compiler is more correct according to standard?

Comment: Try `decltype(func(*this))` instead of `decltype( func( Foo() ) )`

Comment: @0x5453 yes that works thanks. Do you want to make an answer that I can accept?

Comment: For some reason I thought this was out of scope at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `decltype(func(*this))` instead of `decltype( func( Foo() ) )`

I'm not sure whether or not this is standards-compliant, but clang apparently doesn't like using the `Foo()` constructor within the definition of `Foo`.